# Ubuntu Touch: Closing Programs

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there some way of closing programs on Ubuntu-Touch that doesn't involve swiping to the left? I find that I can't reliably close programs using the 'swipe' method.

Comment: Could you file a bug report that swiping to the left doesn't work "reliably"? Or google to see if others have the problem and a solution is available?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the powerful sidebar!

You can open the side bar by swiping from the left edge to the right and stop swiping before the middle of the screen.

The side bar contains your favorite apps plus all apps, which are currently opened. The opened apps are marked with a white dot at the left.

Do a long tap to the app you would like to close.

A little menu opens, which lets you choose to close (Quit) that app.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wasn't able to get the sidebar to work either. However, I seem to have found a fix. It appears that the screen protector I was using on the device was causing the problem. New screen protector and the problem appears to be solved. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yes, you need really to swipe from the edge. It may help, when you begin swiping from beyound the screen's edge.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you are using a device in the converged mode with windowed applicaations, then you can click on a window close button in the title bar area. However, applications which are not in the foreground are paused, and should be automatically killed by the system, if additional memory is required. They may occupy memory in this state, but should not be able to consume any CPU, due to the security restrictions of the system.

It sounds like you may be experiencing a bug that makes it difficult to swipe reliably, in which case you should file a bug report.

Comment: Okay, that's frustrating to hear. It's a nice way to switch programs when it works, but doesn't often enough for me that the OS is not really functional. I plan to wait for the September OTA update and will attempt some other fixes. I may file a bug report if those things don't work. It would be nice though if there were a way to close programs directly.